# Android MediaPlayer keeps downloading even after stopped

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using android.media.MediaPlayer to play an mp3 stream from the Internet. I am using the following code:

```
public void update(String url) {
    try {
        player.stop();
        player.reset();
        player.setDataSource(url);
        player.prepare();
        player.play();
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It works fine except that it keeps downloading data from the old stream when calling update(), so it causes unneccessarily high data usage. So my question is: How to properly stop a MediaPlayer such that it stops downloading?

Comment: Do not call `stop()` if you want to reuse the instance of `MediaPlayer`, call `reset()` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about this, but anyway, the problem still persists.

Comment: I wonder if it happens because the moment you pass new URL path and prepare it, it shouldn't download the old stream. How you're confirming that it's happening ?

Comment: The stream has a bitrate of 128kbps, and when I play the first stream, the data usage is 128kbps. But when I play a second stream with the same bitrate, this increases to 256kbps, and when a third stream URL is passed to update(), the usage is 384kbps and so on.

Comment: Can you show me how you're capturing bitrate ?

Comment: I am using the android emulator, monitor the data usage with the windows task manager and of course confirm that no other process uses the Internet.